# Positional parameter not supported in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am starting to get along with GitHub actions, but cannot figure out a Problem here:

this is my GitHub Action yml:

```
name: Redwood CD for database deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']

env:
  DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}
  TEST_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          # Maps tcp port 5432 on service container to the host
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
   
      # .... here I fetch and build my code which works... 
      # then I want to tar it and deploy it to caprover --> which does not work: 
      - name: Compress action step
        uses: a7ul/tar-action@v1.1.0
        id: compress
        with:
          command: c
          cwd: ./
          files: |
            /home/runner/work/redwood-tutorial/redwood-tutorial/api/dist/
            /home/runner/work/redwood-tutorial/redwood-tutorial/web/dist/
            captain-definition
          outPath: deploy.tar

      - uses: caprover/deploy-from-github@main
        with:
          server: '${{ secrets.CAPROVER_SERVER }}'
          app: '${{ secrets.APP_NAME }}'
          token: '${{ secrets.APP_TOKEN }}'
          branch: '${{ secrets.DEPLOY_BRANCH }}' # optional
          image: '${{ secrets.DEPLOY_IMAGE }}' # optional
```

and this line:
`outPath: deploy.tar` seems to give me the following error:

```
Positional parameter not supported: ./deploy.tar
```

does anyone know what the problem could be here? Google does not really help me here

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of outPath? It must not like the format of one of the inputs: https://github.com/a7ul/tar-action/blob/master/src/index.js#L22

Comment: try `cwd: './'` i think that did the trick for me. at least its the only difference i can find to my current running script